# Переход причастий в другие части речи

Tags: причастия

Пожалуйста,помогите! Задание очень сложное!!!

Какие причастия перешли в ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫЕ, или СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫЕ

> 1) **Сделанное** не вовремя все равно что **не сделанное**.
>
> 2) **Непонимающему** человеку все равно: железо то или уголь.
>
> 3) **Нелающий** пес похлебки не получит.
>
> 4) **Недочитанная** книга все равно что **неоконченный** путь.
>
> 5) **Непровинившемуся** не надо бояться наказания.
>
> 6) Для **знающего** мир светел, для **незнающего** темен.

Может поможет этот источник: http://studopedia.ru/3_40014_I-prichastie.html
Пожалуйста,помогите хоть чем-нибудь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это школа? Лицей? Задание сложное, потому что на этот вопрос есть разные мнения.

1)(Что?) **Сделанное** не вовремя все равно что (что?)**не сделанное.**-Есть признаки существит., но осталось от глагола управление зависимым словом.Какая-то частичная субстантивация, но такое бывает.

2) **Непонимающему** человеку все равно: железо то или уголь.-прилагат., т.к. нет зависимых слов, появилось знач."несведущий", "дилетант".

3) **Нелающий** пес похлебки не получит.прич. перешло в прилагательное, т.к. потеряло глагольность(нет завис. слов, обознач. постоянное качество - ленивый, молчаливый)

4) **Недочитанная** книга все равно что **неоконченный** путь.Недочитанная-книга, которую не дочитали до конца, неоконченный-путь, который кто-то не окончил- я бы  сказала, что это причастие. Хотя тоже появляется качественный оттенок. Сомневаюсь.
5)( Кому?)**Непровинившемуся** не надо бояться наказания.-прич. перешло в сущ.

6) Для (кого?)**знающего** мир светел, для (кого?)**незнающего** темен.-прич. перешло в сущ.

Answer (score 1):

Задание, конечно, интересное, но сложность его решения - это, скорее, следствие неточной терминологии, которая таковой должна быть и в школе, и в лицее.

1) Большая часть причастий подвергается не постоянной (полной), а временной (частичной) адъективизации, то есть в различных случаях может выступать в качестве причастия или прилагательного. Так вот, утрата зависимого слова - это достаточный признак перехода в прилагательное? Тогда во всех случаях мы наблюдаем этот переход.

2) Переход в существительное - это, прежде всего, утрата значения признака и приобретение значения предметности: сделанное, знающий/незнающий, непровинившийся. Кажется, это достаточный признак для перехода?

Answer (score 0):

Неоконченный путь, недочитанная книга  - прилаг. Так как имеется в виду образность:  путь неоконченный вообще, а не не в какой-то определенный момент. Тоже же и с книгой: книга, не прочитанная вообще, а не в какой-то определенный момент. Это т.н. не полная субстантивация. В данных примерах описывается постоянный признак.

Ср.: недочитанная книга  лежала на столе. Здесь вне сомнения причастия. На лицо временной признак.

Comment: Нестареющих-существ.Верующих -существит. А у Вас верящих или верующих? Верящих-неполная субстантивация, есть зависимое слово, но значение предметности проявилось. А вот верующие - точно существительное (как провожающие)